# SQLFORM export redirects to input form

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

I have an application where the user must choose which table he/she wants from a mysql database and it becomes visible in a SQLFORM grid. Nevertheless when the user tries to export the table, for example in csv format the page redirects to the input form and you can export only if you choose the table a second time. This second time you choose the table it makes the application export the data but not make the grid visible. Can you help me out please? This is my controller

```
def show_tables():
    #definetables for the user to choose from

    tables=[db.table1,db.table2...]

    #create the form for user input
    form = SQLFORM.factory(..code here for user to choose the table...)   

    if form.accepts(request.vars,session):     
        query=(...write query icluding chosen table...)

        #display results
        form2=SQLFORM.grid(query=query, create=False, deletable=False, editable=False)
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'Form has errors' #just in case
    return dict(form=form,form2=form2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found a work-around. I redirect the values needed to create the form to a second function and use the corresponding view to display the data.